# Where can I get the source code to LaTeX2HTML?

Tags: html, sourcecode, latex2html

I want to get and improve the source of the `LaTeX2HTML` program, but the top Google results are outdated, with broken links.

Does anyone know where the source resides?

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't already installed on your system?

Comment: @LaoTzu: have you considered using `tex4ht` instead?

Comment: @Raphink I'll check it out. But I want to put up a version on github with better CSS of the more widely used `latex2html`. I've seen too many ugly webpages made with it and want to make a Readability-like view with `MathJAX` rendering instead of gif's.

Comment: @Herbert I'm not sure, but I also don't know where to search on my system (`ubuntu 10.04`).

Comment: @Lao Tzu: run `which latex2htaml` then you'll if it is already there. It is a Perl script

Comment: @Herbert That command produces no output.

Comment: @LaoTzu: then you do not have it installed. Get it from http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latex2html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no single place to get the source as there is no definitive version of the application.

In addition to Peter's answer on the [source code on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latex2html), other places have different versions. This arises as distributors may have the project marked as 'not part of an upstream project', i.e. there is no single place to send copies of downstream changes as there is no known active maintainer. For example, [Ubuntu regards the package in this way](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/latex2html).

As a result there may be differences in the package and the source code depending where you obtain them from. [The version history for Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/latex2html) shows that changes have been promulgated via Debian later than 2008. [The current Ubuntu source and patch file are available to download](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+source/latex2html/2008-debian1-5).

As a result you may find that you have more than one version of the executable available and will need to look at the correct source code package.

On my system, Ubuntu 11.04 but with a full Tex Live 2011 installation, `which latex2html` returns `/usr/bin/latex2html` so I would need the Ubuntu source from the links above or by `apt-get source latex2html` (`sudo` is not needed) rather than the CTAN one.

Answer (score 9):

I would think the source would be at

```
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latex2html
```

The `latex2html-2008.tar.gz` there is dated Sept 2008.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I gave the answer to @mas for its completeness but it could have gone to you too. Cheers.